# Multiple SQL Server- monitoring tool

Tags: sql-server, database, monitoring, locks, utilization

We have around 20 Different physical servers in which SQL Server has been installed and configured( various versions MS SQL servers) 
Need to monitor the complete SQL servers using one tool Which includes Database Performance,  wait time, expensive queries currently executing, Log size utilization, disk space utilization ,Monitor CPU, memory and disk space utilization of the SQL Servers,Get complete details about SQL Server sessions, buffer, memory, locks and latches 
If there is any Microsoft product available then preferred or possible other tools.
Please suggest

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1067/sql-server-performance-monitoring-tools/ For built-in: query store/extended events/performance monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a lot of requirements. FYI, there is no Microsoft tool to manage On-Premise MS SQL Server instances. But, you can create your own utility using SQL scripts or SSIS packages.